# Twitter card not rendering?

Tags: seo, twitter, twitter-card, twitter-integration

I've added this card data to [this site](https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/):

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Firefly Semantics Long Lead Time Capital Intensive Low Demand Service Parts Profit Optimization Help Center">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Long, Lead, Time, Capital, Intensive, Service, Parts, Profit, Optimization, aerospace, heavy, industries">
  <meta name="author" content="Ole Ersoy">  

  <meta name="description" content="Page description. No longer than 155 characters." />

  <!-- Twitter Card data -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="Firefly Semantics Long Lead Time Capital Intensive Low Demand Service Parts Profit Optimization Help Center">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Firefly Semantics Service Parts Help">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Firefly Semantics Long Lead Time Capital Intensive Low Demand Service Parts Profit Optimization Help Center">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@fireflysmtics">
  <-- Twitter Summary card images must be at least 120x120px -->
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://fireflysemantics.github.io/logo/service-parts-help-center/fs-logo-help-center.png">
```

However when I paste a link into my twitter account the card does not render.

https://twitter.com/fireflysmtics

It does Render on medium.  Any ideas?

Here's an example medium article with the card rendering at the end:

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/capital-intensive-concept-c565b5b5eade

It also renders fine on Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your twitter card configuration using the following aplication https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the low quality and square aspect ratio of your twitter image:  https://fireflysemantics.github.io/logo/service-parts-help-center/fs-logo-help-center.png

Twitter renders the card when the image is twice as wide as tall or 16:9 ratio.   A square image should not be used.

A two color image is not high quality.  Most twitter cards contain much higher quality images.